Drow Matron Mother Telekinetic Throw
As a lair action, the Drow Matron Mother has:

Telekinetic Throw. The drow targets one creature she can see within 60 feet of her and attempts to expel it from her presence. The target must succeed on a DC 19 Strength saving throw or be flung 2d6 × 10 feet through the air. A creature smashed into a solid object takes 1d6 bludgeoning damage for every 10 feet moved. If released in midair, the creature takes falling damage as normal.

How much control does the Mother have over the direction of the throw?
Can it be towards her, or does "expel it from her presence" imply it has to be 'away'?
If it has to be 'away', does it have to be directly away (that is, following line of sight from her to the target), or is ending the move farther from the mother than it started sufficient?
Is the distance flung measured only laterally on the grid, or can the fling include changing elevation and be measured in three dimensions?  Can the Mother deliberately fling a creature 'up' (entirely or partially) and thus have it 'released in midair'?
Is the damage based on how far the fling went or could have gone?
If the fling is ended by smashing into a solid object, is the damage based on the distance rolled regardless, or is it based on the distance actually moved up until the fling was cut short?
I am most interested in RAW, but I suspect the ability is just vaguely worded and there is no RAW.  I would accept RAI with an argument made based on other telekinetic abilities such as spells or psionics.

You can throw them in any direction, if the DM agrees
The text could have said "thrown away", but it just said "through the air". Compare this, for example with the language of Shove

you can make a special melee attack to shove a creature, either to knock it prone or push it away from you.

Or with Thunderwave:

On a failed save, a creature takes 2d8 thunder damage and is pushed 10 feet away from you.

These features usually use the language "away from you" if they mean away from you.
When the action says the target can be "released midair", I believe this means that you can just throw them up. And that also would support that you cannot only throw them straight away from you. In a special setup, it might also be possible to push a creature over a chasm into the air, and it would then fall at the end of the push, but that is kind of normal and obvious, so I don't see why you would need to spend text on calling that out. None of this is entirely airtight though, so in the end up to the DM.
As an evil matron mother, you might also "expel" someone from your presence, by smashing them into the wall next to you and killing them. Then they are not someone, they are just a corpse, conveniently to be animated as a servant, as it befits them. So I think, the Matron Mother should be able to throw the target in whatever direction she damn well pleases. Of course, if your DM thinks otherwise, they have the last word.
The creature takes damage based on the distance actually moved

A creature smashed into a solid object takes 1d6 bludgeoning damage for every 10 feet moved.

If you roll 70 feet and they smash into a wall after 20 feet, they have not moved 70 feet, they have moved 20 feet. So they take damage by how far they moved, 20 feet. This one I think is pretty clear.

For "released midair", I assume this is to give the Matron a bit more control. For example, a 70 foot push across a 40 foot cavern would see the victim dropped halfway, rather than safely deposited on the other side.
